# List notebooks in OneDrive for Business

Tags: onedrive, onenote, onenote-api

Using the OneNote API I am unable to view notebooks created by others in OneDrive. No error message displayed, it just doesn't list the notebook shared by others through shared folder in OneDrive for business.  Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The OneNote API for Business doesn't show shared notebooks unlike the version authenticated by a personal Microsoft account.

The OneNote team's reason here is that the flat list of all notebooks a user has access to would not scale in an enterprise environment.  The intent is to  add a different resource to represent shared notebooks, which will be retrofitted to the consumer API.  However this has not been done yet, and there is no ETA as of August 2015.